# How to get Balance working on biteBTC Trading API using Singapore timestamp getting unauthorized error

Tags: python, api

```
import hashlib
import pytz
import hmac
from time import time
import urllib
import requests
import datetime


class BiteBtc:
    def __init__(self):
        self.api_key = b'LvC6D-OMpm2tc-KNpGR-KOxQFukC318D'
        self.secret_key = b'r40u3jrWUDMfhHyMNNpxbPwsDPnkAoeVMJTzUhlm3cHHUXjRHLKdeiAtiqCEudlz'

    def get_balance(self):
        url = 'https://bitebtc.com/api/v1/trading/balances'
        payload = {
            'currencies': 'btc'
        }

        paybytes = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload).encode('utf8')

        ###
        sgt = pytz.timezone("Asia/Singapore")
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        ts = now.astimezone(sgt).timestamp()
        ts = round(float(ts), 3)  # mili-sec
        nonce = str(ts).replace(".", "")
        ###


        headers = {
            'x-api-tonce': nonce,  #str(int(time() * 1000)),
            'x-api-key': self.api_key,
            'x-api-signature': hmac.new(self.secret_key, paybytes, 
hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
        }

        r = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=paybytes)
        return r.json()

bite=BiteBtc()
print(bite.get_balance())
```

Comment: Hey, are you sure you want to make your API key and secret key public? You should reset it ASAP before you face some unwanted charges.

Comment: Thats just a testing account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should make sure the API is 'enabled' over at https://bitebtc.com/profile/keys. It's disabled by default and I had the same problem but that fixed it up.